# Python: Log multiple strings to one line

Tags: python, string, logging

Title says it all, I need to log two strings in one line.
For example, something like this:

```
logging.info(string1,string2)
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The logging functions act like this:

```
result = arg1 % (arg2, arg3, ...)
```

What you have will try to format the first string with the second string:

```
result = string1 % string2
```

Either manually specify a formatting string:

```
logging.info('%s %s', string1, string2)
```

Or join them together into one string:

```
logging.info(' '.join([string1, string2]))
```

Comment: You forgot the simple case of `string1 + string2`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use %-formatting, like this:

```
logging.info("%s %s", string1, string2)
```

For example:

```
 >>> string1, string2 = "spam", "pie"
 >>> logging.info("%s %s", string1, string2)
 INFO: spam pie
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> ( s1,s2 ) = ( 'apple','mango' );
>>> print( '{},{}'.format(s1,s2) );
apple,mango
```

Answer (score 2):

Using f strings, you could turn this into a one-liner and make it quite readable.

```
# python3 f-strings
logging.info(f'{string1} {string2}')
```

Comment: Not a good practice to do so. For more details, check https://www.palkeo.com/en/blog/python-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

```
logger.info("String 1: {0!r} --- String 2: {1!r}".format(string1, string2))
```

Demo:

```
>>> print "String 1: {0!r} --- String 2: {1!r}".format('hello', 'world')
String 1: 'hello' --- String 2: 'world'
>>> print "String 1: {1!r} --- String 2: {0!r}".format('world', 'hello')
String 1: 'hello' --- String 2: 'world'
```

Two things to note here:

1. The number in {0!r} and {1!r} specify the argument you get from
   input.
2. '!s' (apply str()) and '!r' (apply repr()) can be used to convert
   the value before it is formatted.